# Usage for Widgets

Tags: psychology, wireframe

Can we consider a widget as a good re-presenter of latest activities, e.g: Latest News, Latest Announcements, Latest Offers..and so on ?
And Does it make sense to put a widget among the content? I think it should be located in the side bar.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague in the context of widgets: what constitutes as "a widget"? You might get better answers if you could explain your data, page and situation more.

Comment: @Jawa I assume he means Widget in the Android OS context, sort of like desktop widgets for windows 7/google desktop (remeber those like 4 years ago?) Passive interface elements that actively updated and could be interacted with, but weren't full applications. But regardless he should expound more on his definition of widget so we can better help.

Answer (score 1):

A "widget" can be seen as more of an implementation methodology than just a UI component or concept. Whether to use widgets or some other means depends greatly on the framework or platform. Nonetheless, I think that the "Latest ..." you describe are good candidates to be implemented as widgets.

If it's reasonable to have just the latest news or latest announcements as the main content, the question is kind of meaningless. I'd say that if the latest of X has no meaning when mixed within the content, the widgets should stay separately in the sidebar or at the bottom of the page.

And one example of the reverse; if your content has some entities (e.g. persons or organizations) you could put a small (perhaps expanding) widget in direct proximition of the entity to give shortcuts to recent news or activities related to the person or organization.

Comment: Thanks Jawa,, Actually my main content is places related, and the latest offers and announcements would be for those the places make, my concern was about the possibility of including these updates in a widget, and the best location to add this widget (side bar or within the content).